# Why does Wikipedia list these two solutions?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_logarithmic_functions) has the two integrals

$$\int x^m\ln x\,dx = x^{m+1}\left(\frac{\ln x}{m+1}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^2}\right) \qquad\mbox{(for }m\neq -1\mbox{)}$$

and

$$\int \frac{\ln x\,dx}{x^\hat{m}} = -\frac{\ln x}{(\hat{m}-1)x^{\hat{m}-1}}-\frac{1}{(\hat{m}-1)^2 x^{\hat{m}-1}} \qquad\mbox{(for }\hat{m}\neq 1\mbox{)}.$$

Shouldn't they be identical for $$\hat{m}=-m$$ or am I missing something?

Comment: they are, as far as I can tell?

Comment: They are identical. As to the question "*Why* does Wikipedia list these two solutions?" -> I guess, for convenience of the reader.

Comment: Anybody with any background can edit Wikipedia. If you think it's redundant then you can go ahead and change it. Fair warning: the editor interface of wiki is terrible.